# How to edit the code of a library imported with Gradle in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-library

I'm facing a little problem with one of my libraries in Android Studio. This one is imported with a Gradle file, like this :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
}
```

It has a known issue from its GitHub repository but I can only fix it by editing one line of code in a file of this library... The problem is that I can't find its code in Android Studio.

From another Stackoverflow post, I've found this :

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea{
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
```

But after applying it and reloading my Gradle configuration, I still can't find the code.

Can you help?

Thanks!

Comment: "The problem is that I can't find its code in Android Studio" -- that is because you do not have its code in Android Studio. You have added the AAR file as a dependency, which does not contain Java source code, but rather compiled Java bytecode. But you know where [the project's GitHub repository is](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary). Clone the repo, then use the library as a library module in your project, instead of the AAR you are pulling in, until such time as the AAR is patched.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Thank you! I finally used your solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can also extend that class and override that method. After overriding just update the code according to your need and solve that bug and use your new class :-)